# Bootstrap Datepicker in Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, bootstrap-4

I use Laravel bootstrap and date picker, as you can see below this is the code, I already make sure that the date format run correctly, but the todayHighlight: false is not working and the container is not working as well

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datepicker_modal').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            container: $(this).closest('.dateContainer'),
            todayHighlight: false
        });
    });
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success mx-1" data-toggle="modal" data-placement="bottom" title="Approve" data-target="#accept_1">
        Click to Show
    </button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="accept_1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
          <div class="modal-accept modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-success text-light">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><strong>ACCEPT </strong></h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
            </div>
            <form method="POST" action="">
              <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group dateContainer">
                  <label for="date_pick">Date</label>
                  <input id="date_pick" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" class="form-control datepicker_modal" name="date_pick" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">CANCEL</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">ACCEPT</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

but in my Laravel project, [the date picker is floating and still highlight the current date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfqbH.jpg)
Is there any idea that can I solve this one?

Answer (score 0):

Add `startDate` in your js :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datepicker_modal').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            startDate: "12-12-2020",
            container:'#myModalId',
            todayHighlight: false
        });
    });
</script>
```

container attribute can solve position :

```
<input id="date_pick" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" type="text" data-date-container='#myModalId' class="form-control datepicker_modal" name="date_pick" autocomplete="off" required>
```

Comment: from the documentation: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate, that the start date will make user unable to choose date before 12-12-20  http://prntscr.com/t5py9t